# Spring boot application start generate Unsupported class file major version 65 after java 21 migration

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-21

I migrated a Spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE application from Java 11 to Java 21.
In the first step I just do a simple java migration and maybe if I have time I will do an upgrade of dependencies.
Now the Spring boot application compile fine but when I run it in Intellij the process stop quicly

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

22-02-2024 16:25:30.645 main INFO  com.omb.app.MyProjectApplication.logStarting - Starting MyProjectApplication on MY_LAPTOP with PID 8452 (C:\dev\sources\myProject\myProject\target\classes started by mbou in C:\dev\sources\myProject\myProject)
22-02-2024 16:25:30.653 main DEBUG com.omb.app.MyProjectApplication.logStarting - Running with Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.2.RELEASE
22-02-2024 16:25:30.654 main INFO  com.omb.app.MyProjectApplication.logStartupProfileInfo - The following profiles are active: dev

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I try to run the jar manualy with the java -jar command and I add this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/dev/sources/myProject/myProject/target/myProject-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ch/tl/myProject/app/ApplicationConf
ig.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: URL [jar:file:/C:/dev/sources/myProject/myProject/
target/myProject-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ch/tl/myProject/app/ApplicationConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65                                              
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]               
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]               
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                          
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                             
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                 
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                   
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                  
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                             
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                   
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                               
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                            
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                    
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]                                              
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                    
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                             
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                        
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                       
        at com.omb.app.MyProjectApplication.main(MyProjectApplication.java:30) ~[classes!/:na]                                                                                                                                              
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]                                                                                                                     
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]                                                                                                                                                                
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[myProject-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]                                                                                                                    
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[myProject-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]                                                                                                                                
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[myProject-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]                                                                                                                                 
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[myProject-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]                                                                                                                             
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: URL [jar:file:/C:/dev/sources/myProject/myProject/target/myProject-0.3.0
-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ch/tl/myProject/app/ApplicationConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65                                                                  
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                      
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                              
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                    
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                  
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]               
        ... 26 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65                                                                                                                                                        
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:58) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]                                                                      
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

You can find here my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.omb</groupId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.omb.rc</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <core.version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</core.version>
        <core-rest.version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</core-rest.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.omb.rc</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${core-rest.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.omb.rc</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>4.12</version> -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/tools-application-*.properties</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/keystore/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/logback-spring.xml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.omb.app.MyProjectApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.30</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.omb.app.MyProjectApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.jrcodeza</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-openapi-client-generator-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generateClientFromOpenApi</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaPath>${project.basedir}/reference/OJP.v1.yaml_WORK_JSON</schemaPath>
                        <outputPath>target/generated-sources</outputPath>
                        <outputPackage>com.omb</outputPackage>
                        <generateDiscriminatorProperty>true</generateDiscriminatorProperty>
                        <generateResourceInterface>true</generateResourceInterface>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Spring boot in that old version does not support JDK21... furthermore why changing configuration of maven-jar-plugin etc. also mixing different Spring Boot versions 2.2.2.RELEASE with 2.7.4 etc. If you want to migrate I strongly recommend to go first 2.2.X.RELEASe (x most recent version) after that migrate to 2.3.X.. and so on up until reaching 2.7.X and then go to 3.0.0 and 3.1.0, 3.2.0 and with Spring Boot 3.0 start using JDK 17 and if you reached most recent version of 3.2.2 and change to JDK 21..

Comment: .also use more recent versions of open-api generators (https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md) etc. (this one https://github.com/jrcodeza/spring-openapi is out of date as well)

Answer (score 0):

The ASM library used inside spring boot to manipulate byte code before being processed by the class loader, is too old to understand Java 21 byte codes.

You should only use versions of Java explicitly supported by the version of Spring Boot you use.  In your case that may mean that you have to upgrade to the latest version of Spring Boot. Consider it paying technical debt.